# Cloned ASP.NET MVC 3 application from github shows yellow exclamation marks next to every Nuget'd package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, github, nuget, nuget-package

Every DLL that comes by way of NuGet shows an exclamation mark against a yellow background after cloning the ASP.NET MVC project from github.  The problem appears to be the PATH which is absolute rather than relative, meaning that it shows the initial developer's absolute path which in my case is different than mine.

So ...

Is there a way to force Nuget to use relative paths?  Or, is there a way to simply use Nuget to update all of these from within the project?  Or, is there a better way to work with NuGet in a github environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable Package Restore on your project. That will cause Nuget to download any missing dlls on build. They shouldn't be absolute anyway but this will take care of it if they're missing.

You can right click the solution in Visual Studio and choose "Enable Nuget Package Restore"

Old blog post: 
http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/08/easy-way-to-set-up-nuget-to-restore.html